# The differential entropy of the sum of independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable with density $f$. The differential entropy is defined by
$$h(X):=-\int_{\mathbb R^d} f(x)log(f(x))dx.$$

The conditional entropy is defined by replacing the density with conditional density.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables with densities. I want to show 
$$h(X+Y)> h(X).$$

I feel like we probably need the formula for the chain rule of conditional entropy somewhere, like $h(X+Y)=h(X,X+Y)-h(X|X+Y)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it directly like this
\begin{align*}
h(X)&=h(X|Y)\\
&=h(X+Y|Y)\\
&\leq h(X+Y)
\end{align*}

We can show the inequality is strict by observing that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $\text{Cov}(X,Y)=0$ which means that
\begin{align*}
\text{Cov}(X+Y,Y) &= \mathbb E[(X+Y-\mathbb E[X+Y]))(Y-\mathbb E[Y])]\\
&=\text{Cov}(X,Y)+\text{Var}(Y)\\
&=\text{Var}(Y)\\
&>0
\end{align*}
So $X+Y$ and $Y$ are not independent hence $0<I(X+Y;Y)=h(X+Y)-h(X+Y|Y)$ which proves your statement.

$\text{Var}(Y)>0$ is a sufficient condition but may not be necessary.

---

Let's prove that $h(X|Y)=h(X+Y|Y)$. We can write 
\begin{align*}
h(X|Y)&=-\int p_Y(y) \int p_{X|Y}(x|y) \log p_{X|Y}(x|y) dy\\
&=-\int p_Y(y) \int p_{X+Y|Y}(x+y|y) \log p_{X+Y|Y}(x+y|y) dy\\
&=h(X+Y|Y)
\end{align*}
By a change of variable $p_{X+Y|Y}(x+y|y)=p_{X|Y}(x|y)$.

Comment: Okay... but a constant doesn't have a density right?

Comment: Also $h(X|Y)=h(X+Y|Y)$ looks simple (One doesn't gain new information from $X+Y$ if they are given $Y$) but pretty hard to prove, Could you provide more details?

Comment: @NoOne For the last comment, see my edit. I'm not sure what you mean by "have a density", does that mean that $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables ?

Comment: Thanks! I meant I think some functions, like constants or indicator functions, don't have densities... But let me think about it...